# php How to sort and brake while loop based on variable

Tags: php, while-loop

I have a problem ... I can not solve it for two days. I am a beginner in php.

i don't understand why while loop returns me as much selects fields as every select field has options, for example field "choose color" has 3 options, red green and yellow and i get instead one select field 3 of them... see this http://5dstudio.eu/select.jpg
structure of my data base looks like this:
http://5dstudio.eu/data.jpg

my php code:

```
<?php 
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT qty FROM attributes ORDER BY qty ");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
$name_attribute = $row["qty"];
$num = (int)$name_attribute;
    echo "<select>";
        $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM attributes WHERE qty='$name_attribute' ORDER BY qty");
        while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){
        $value_attribute = $row2["name"];

        echo '<option>' ."$value_attribute". '</option>';

        }
    echo "</select>";
}
?>
```

Thanks for any tips and help!

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated. I understand you're new to PHP, but please change over to using mysqli as soon as possible. Otherwise, I don't understand your question.

Comment: You really shouldn't be making queries like this. Use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your first query to this:

```
SELECT qty FROM attributes GROUP BY qty
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT qty FROM attributes
```

Comment: no problem. Do yo understand why you were getting that result? Also feel free to give me a check mark.

Comment: Yes I understand - MySQL by default returns all the values ​​regardless of whether they are the same or not, if you do not want to duplicate the results then let's use the DISTINCT operator.